# What is different with pickled data between 3.2 (wheezy) and 3.4 (jessie)?

Tags: python, pickle

I have a python 3.x client that runs on a raspberry pi. It provides camera setting information to a server running winpython 3.4 by pickling on the PI and unpickling on the server.

This works fine when the pi is running wheezy and python 3.2, but when I try it on a PI running jessy and python 3.4 the unpickle fails on the server, with the error:

```
File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 260, in loads
    return load(file)

  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 250, in load
    obj = pik.load()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\pickle.py", line 1036, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\pickle.py", line 1323, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)

  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 406, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\pickle.py", line 1373, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)

**ImportError: No module named 'picamera'**
```

As you can see from the error, this is after I installed Dill on the server but I still get the same basic error, it cant find picamera.

I then installed PICamera on the server, but of course this fails as it looks for Raspberry I files, so uninstalled it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to make the 3.4 python version of pickling work the same as 3.2 version ?

Thanks

update:

@Dilettant thanks for the hint to use pickle tools. I found a difference within the pickle:   3.4 version pickles this item as a picamera entry, 3.2 leaves it as a tuple.
3.4 results -->

530: q        BINPUT     36
532: K        BININT1    0
534: X        BINUNICODE 'resolution'
549: q        BINPUT     37
551: c           GLOBAL     'picamera.mmalobj PiCameraResolution'

```
 3.2 version -->
```

830: q        BINPUT     55
832: \x88     NEWTRUE
833: X           BINUNICODE 'resolution'
848: q        BINPUT     56
850: M           BININT2    720
853: M        BININT2    480
856: \x86     TUPLE2

when I fix it I will post the results

Comment: Protocol version 4 was added in Python 3.4 - so maybe try to force a lower protocol version? If this does not help, maybe some more details obtained via pickletools?

Comment: @Dilettant This problem isn't related to protocol 4. If it was, the error would occur much sooner

Comment: I did check the protocols and both are reporting default value of 3

Answer (score 0):

`pickle` is a format which is tightly related to the python bytecode of the object you want to serialize. The bytecode may change from on python version to an other. Therefor you can only exchange pickeled data between programs which are run with the same python version.

You can use for example the `json` module to serialize your data in order to send it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Dilettant, @Sebastian Stigler,@ppperry

The issue is an undocumented change to the base PiCamera class providing the resolution data that is being pickled. Originally it provided a Tuple, and now a 'picamera.mmalobj.PiCameraResolution' object. I added a check to see if the object was a tuple or not and handled the data accordingly. I hope this helps others in the same position.

```
    if type(camera.resolution) == tuple:
        settings["resolution"] = camera.resolution
    else:
        settings["resolution"] = (camera.resolution.width,camera.resolution.height)
```